# Display Alert in ScrollView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift2, uialertview

I have this issue here.

I got this class `public class ImageSlideshowItem: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate {` inside a library that i'm using.
So i want to add an alertController inside the `scrollView` but I get an error using this code

```
func saveImage() {

     UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.imageView.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)
}

func image(image: UIImage!, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError!, contextInfo: AnyObject!) {
    if (error != nil) {
        // Something wrong happened.
        print("not saved")
    } else {
        // Everything is alright.
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        var fullscree: FullScreenSlideshowViewController = FullScreenSlideshowViewController()
        // show the alert
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

And the error it this one.

> Value of type 'ImageSlideshowItem' has no member 'presentViewController'

Any idea of how can I display the alert?

Update:

Here is the link of another class that i call ImageSlideshowItems

["ImageSlideshow"](http://paste.ofcode.org/39HK25NjDQYS2PxQJF46Wbj)

And here is the complete ImageSlideShowItem class

["ImageSlideshowItems"](http://paste.ofcode.org/ks2YQNSUWPiXuBTaNFMzRC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that `ScrollView` is type of `UIView` object not a `controller`, so that you are not getting `presentViewController` inside that child class of `ScrollView`, to solved the problem you can try like this, create one `UIViewController` instance inside that class, and use that instance to present the alertController, when you initialzed the `scrollView`, on any `ViewController`, just pass the reference of that `viewController` like this

```
public class ImageSlideshowItem: UIScrollView, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var viewController: UIViewController?

    func image(image: UIImage!, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError!, contextInfo: AnyObject!) {
        if (error != nil) {
            // Something wrong happened.
            print("not saved")
        } else {
            // Everything is alright.
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            // add an action (button)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            var fullscree: FullScreenSlideshowViewController = FullScreenSlideshowViewController()
            // show the alert
            self.viewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)              
        }
    }  

}
```

Now pass the instance of current ViewController with your `scrollView` object.

```
let imgslider = ImageSlideshowItem() 
imgslider.viewController = self
```

Comment: The only thing that i don't understand here is where to pass the instance of current ViewController?

`let imgslider = ImageSlideshowItem() 
imgslider.viewController = self`

Comment: Where you are creating object of `ImageSlideshowItem` class. inside some viewController, right pass reference of that viewController using `self`

Comment: Ok, i get this error `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'ImageSlideshowItem' with no arguments`

Comment: Can you update the question with code you are initializing the object of `ImageSlideshowItem` class.

Comment: You are getting this errror because you have override the `init` method so you need to create object like this `let imgslider = ImageSlideshowItem(inputSourceobj, zoomEnabled: false)`.

Comment: Also i am i asking you to add the code where you have created object of this class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121140/discussion-between-ndoc-and-kwnstantinos-natsios).